# Android. How to load paging data from specific position with Paging 3?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-viewpager2, android-paging-3

I'm using `paging3` for showing endless list in `RecyclerView`. When I click in specific item I need to show detail fragment. The detail fragment contains a view pager whose adapter is also `PagingDataAdapter`. That is, a fragment with detailed information should show the element that I selected on the previous screen and it is also possible to scroll horizontally to other elements that are also loaded page by page.
The problem is that I can't start displaying the paging list in my view pager from a certain position. The list is always displayed from the beginning. I can't found solution for this. Is it possible to start listening to data from Page Source (RemoteMediator) beginning from specific position ?
Please, help me:(

Answer (score 1):

you can find the [LimitOffsetPagingSource](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/room/room-paging/src/main/java/androidx/room/paging/LimitOffsetPagingSource.kt) and check the **getRefreshKey**.
i guess the **getRefreshKey** return a wrong key by **PagingState.anchorPosition** because you set a **Pager.initialKey**